# Eclipse/Android SDK won't let me select a 'Build SDK' option when starting a new activity

Tags: android, eclipse, windows-7, sdk

I am attempting to use the android plugin for eclipse (Indigo), and I've gotten it to work once.  Unfortunately the machine I am using has a 'deep freeze' program on it, and so I've had to install the SDK several times in order to use it.  I have permision from the system administrator to install the SDK permanently, but I cannot seem to get it installed correctly.  My problem is as follows:

I follow the instalation instructions found on http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html, have a few problems making Windows recognize the fact that the JDK is already installed (which I work through), and then complete the installation.  I attempt to create a new Android project and in step 1 of the project creation the drop down bar labelled 'Build SDK' is completely blank, and the 'next', 'back', and 'finish' buttons are all dark and unclickable.

I'm not quite sure what I've done differently from installation to installation (of the SDK).  Any help or suggestions would be apreciated.

Comment: are you sure you installed the Android SDK properly? If so, which platforms did u install? Also were there any errors during installation?

Comment: @ParthDoshi I'm fairly sure I have.  Of course I'm not infallible.  I'm going to try re-installing yet again and see if there's anything I missed.  But I'm pretty sure I followed the instructions pretty precisely.